# When should I count total records in jquery DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I want to check total records in jquery DataTable and hide/show "No record Found" message. Currently I checked total rows in "fnDrawCallback" section like this but I shows "no record found" when I navigate too fast:

```
  //Instantiate the Datatable
    function configureDataTable() {

        var url = prepareURLforDataTable();

        $scope.table = $('#example').dataTable({                   
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": url,
            "sAjaxDataProp": "aoData",
            "bProcessing": false,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bInfo": true,
            "bSort": false,
            "searching": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "iDisplayLength": 7,            

            "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                //to hide or show no record message    
                var rowsData = $('#example').DataTable().rows().data();
                $scope.count = rowsData.length;
                if ($scope.count == 0) {
                    $scope.ShowNoRecordMsg();
                }
                else {
                    $scope.HideNoRecordMsg();
                }
                $rootScope.hideSpinner();
               //other operations
```

I have two Div section one for "no records" and other for "conversation table". $scope.ShowNoRecordMsg & $scope.HideNoRecordMsg remove *display: none* from "no records" div & "conversation table" div respectively..

Comment: defer it slightly, maybe debounce too.

Comment: @dandavis What do you mean exactly...?